# Acesso a diretório do cliente

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho uma curiosidade, alguém sabe me dizer se existe algum jeito de fazer minha aplicação web (no caso ASP .Net core) conseguir deixar o usuário escolher uma pasta na sua máquina local e, a minha aplicação ter acesso aos arquivos dentro desta pasta que o usuário escolheu?

Bom seria como um jeito de fazer a leitura dos arquivos em uma pasta na máquina do cliente, para que assim que ele faça alguma alteração em algum arquivo ou insira um novo arquivo, a aplicação detectar essa mudança, porém na propria máquina do cliente sem que ele precise fazer o upload manualmente.

Quem puder dar uma ideia vou agradecer bastante. Obrigado!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, até onde sei sem fazer o upload é impossível pois isso é uma falha de segurança caso isso pudesse ocorrer...

O que você pode fazer é criar um client para que seu usuário instale e este faz o upload de forma automática para seu site/sistema.

Comment: Ah certo é verdade, faz todo sentido. Valeu Ivan me deu algumas ideias de como fazer obrigado.